# inequality with absolute value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the given inequality by interpreting it as a statement about distance on the real line:

$$|x+1| \gt|x-3|$$

anyone know how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case-by-case analysis.

Note that the absolute value function changes when its argument is $0$. Then, this equation will change whenever the argument of an absolute value is negative, or positive.

The first one: $x+1=0\rightarrow x=-1$. The second one: $x-3=0\rightarrow x=3$

So, the equation will change at $x=-1$ and $x=3$. Then,

1) $x<-1$

In this case,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
-(x+1)&>&-(x-3)\\
-x-1&>&-x+3\\
-1&>&3\quad \rightarrow\leftarrow\\
\end{array}$$

That's a contradiction, so there's no solutions in this interval, so there's no $x<-1$ that verify the inequality:
$$S_1: \emptyset$$

2) $-1\leq x < 3$

in this case,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(x+1)&>&-(x-3)\\
x+1&>&-x+3\\
2x&>&2\\
x&>&1
\end{array}$$

All $x>1$ are solutions. But, as we were working under the condition $-1\leq x < 3$, we intersect the intervals, so the solution is 
$$S_2: 1<x<3=\,x\in(1,3)$$

3) $3\leq x$

In this case,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(x+1)&>&(x-3)\\
x+1&>&x-3\\
1&>&-3\\
\end{array}$$

All $x$ are solutions in this case! But, as we were working under the condition $3\leq x$, we intersect the intervals, so the solution is 
$$S_3:3\leq x=\,x\in[3,\infty)$$

---

Finally, the solution is given by all cases. As the cases were independent, we only union all intervals:
$$S=S_1 \cup S_2\cup S_3 = \emptyset \cup (1,3) \cup [3,\infty)=(1,\infty)$$

Comment: yo dude, you're legend, can I ask you one question tho? how came the union of those two intervals aer (1,infinity)?

Comment: I don't know the notation for "closed intervals" you use regularly. In my case, $x\in(a,b)$ is the same as $a<x<b$, and $x\in[a,b]$ is the same as $a\leq x \leq b$. Then, $S_2:\,1<x<3$ and $S_3:\,3\leq z < \infty$. So, $S_2\cup S_3 = 1<x<\infty = (1,\infty)$ because the number $3$ is included in $S_3$

Comment: for sure! thanks a lot for showing this method!

Comment: Also, note that case-by-case analysis is the most accurate way to solve this kind of inequalities (and equalities too!). I tried to be as clear as posible so you could repeat the procedure. Try to solve another excersise by yourself!

Answer (score 4):

I'll formulate the inequality in words: you are looking for points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ whose distance from $-1$ is greater than its distance from $3$.

Draw the real line and the points $-1$ and $3$. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$|x-a|$ represents the distance of a point $x$ from a fixed point $a$. For example, in your case $|x+1|$ means the distance of point $x$ from the point $-1$. Now try to interpret the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to know the following way. Since both sides $\ge 0$, we have
$$|x+1|\gt |x-3|\iff |x+1|^2\gt |x-3|^2\iff x^2+2x+1\gt x^2-6x+9$$$$\iff 2x+1\gt -6x+9\iff (2+6)x\gt 9-1\iff x\gt 1.$$

Comment: @yeyeeyey123321: Is this what you want?

Comment: yeah, just like this! thanks a lot

Comment: @yeyeeyey123321: You are welcome. I added a bit.

Comment: ahh ok can I ask you for another question as well? |x-1|=1-x , how can I solve that?

Comment: Note that this way of solving may insert answers, because of the squaring. Cases like $|x-1|<x$ (where there are terms without absolute value) could give false answers.

Comment: @yeyeeyey123321: Separate it into cases: if $x-1\ge 0$, then you have $x-1=1-x$. If $x-1\lt 0$, then $-(x-1)=1-x$.

Comment: ahh alright, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Where must 'point' $x$ be situated if its distance to $-1$ exceeds
its distance to $+3$?

$----\bullet_{-1}-----\bullet_{0}-----\bullet_{+1}-----\bullet_{+2}-----\bullet_{+3}----$